# displaying hidden html via a button with javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble showing a hidden div field on my rails app. Below is the code:

```
  # application.js file 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "button.click-c", function() {
      $("div.refresh").show();
      console.log("is this going to console")
      //$("div.refresh").toggle();
      //alert("test");
    });
  });
```

View page:

```
<button type="button" class="click-c" onclick="click">click</button>
<div id="refresh" class="hidden" >
  <p> hidden content line <%= display info %> </p>
</div>
```

Also for applciation.css I have:

```
 .hidden { display: none; }
```

For the JS code, I tried both .toggle and .show. The button is working on alert("test") and is also printing to the console. Why is it that when the button is clicked, it will not display the hidden lines?

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the *div* with `id` as `refresh` but you are using it as `class name` in *JS* code

```
$("div.refresh").show();
```

Should be

```
$("div#refresh").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Pavan said you have to change `class`. to `id`# *[Pavan's answer is the correct answer if you have one button and one refresh.hidden element]*.. But if you have multiple buttons and hidden elements

Id must be unique so don't duplicate ids .. see the next demo

```js
//# application.js file 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "button.click-c", function() {
    $("div.hidden").not($(this).next('div.hidden')).hide();
    console.log("is this going to console")
    $(this).next('div.hidden').slideToggle();
    //alert("test");
  });
});
```

```css
.click-c{
  display: block;
}
.hidden { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="click-c">click</button>
  <div id="refresh1" class="hidden">
  <p> hidden content line <%= display info %> </p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="click-c">click</button>
  <div id="refresh2" class="hidden">
  <p> hidden content line <%= display info %> </p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="click-c">click</button>
  <div id="refresh3" class="hidden">
  <p> hidden content line <%= display info %> </p>
</div>
```